# Deleting a calendar event using Google's Python client library

Tags: python, google-calendar-api, google-api-python-client

This seems to be such a simple thing, but I seem to not be able to delete an event in Google Calendar using the library.

With my code, I comment out the "delete event" code and run, which inserts an event and then lists that event. I also check to make sure I can see it in the UI. I then take the id from the event that was created and then put that as the `eventId` in the "delete event" call. Then I uncomment the deletion code and comment out the insertion code and run it again.

This approach doesn't seem to work: I still see the event listed in the `events().list` output, and I still see it in the UI.

```
# Delete Event
resp = service.events().delete(calendarId='primary', eventId='9c9ppp94isp15103t54mtjss8s')
pprint(vars(resp))
print('Event Deleted')


# Inserts Event
GMT_OFF = '-07:00'    # PDT/MST/GMT-7
EVENT = {
    'summary': 'Test Event2',
    'start':   {'dateTime': '2018-09-15T19:00:00%s' % GMT_OFF},
    'end':     {'dateTime': '2018-09-15T22:00:00%s' % GMT_OFF},
}

e = service.events().insert(calendarId='primary', sendNotifications=True, body=EVENT).execute()

print('''*** %r event added:
Start: %s
End:   %s''' % (e['summary'].encode('utf-8'),
    e['start']['dateTime'], e['end']['dateTime']))



# Read Events
now = datetime.datetime.utcnow().isoformat() + 'Z' # 'Z' indicates UTC time
print('Getting the upcoming 10 events')
events_result = service.events().list(calendarId='primary', timeMin=now,
                                    maxResults=10, singleEvents=True,
                                    orderBy='startTime').execute()
events = events_result.get('items', [])

if not events:
    print('No upcoming events found.')
for event in events:
    start = event['start'].get('dateTime', event['start'].get('date'))
    print(start, event['id'], event['summary'])
```

When I print out the delete response (`pprint(vars(resp))`) it looks like this:

```
{'_in_error_state': False,
 '_rand': <built-in method random of Random object at 0x7f9ac007e420>,
 '_sleep': <built-in function sleep>,
 'body': None,
 'body_size': 0,
 'headers': {'accept': '*/*',
         'accept-encoding': 'gzip, deflate',
         'user-agent': 'google-api-python-client/1.7.4 (gzip)'},
 'http': <httplib2.Http object at 0x1051cd250>,
 'method': u'DELETE',
 'methodId': u'calendar.events.delete',
 'postproc': <bound method RawModel.response of 
 <googleapiclient.model.RawModel object at 0x1052e9290>>,
 'response_callbacks': [],
 'resumable': None,
 'resumable_progress': 0,
 'resumable_uri': None,
 'uri': u'https://www.googleapis.com/calendar/v3/calendars/primary/events/9c9ppp94isp15103t54mtjss8s?'}
```

If I copy the `uri` from the delete response above and use Postman, the event is deleted without a problem. Ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Per the Python API Client documentation, [calling an API endpoint does not submit the call, but rather constructs the relevant `HttpRequest` object:](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/python/start/get_started#methods-and-requests)

> Every collection has a list of methods defined by the API. Calling a collection's method returns an [`HttpRequest`](http://google.github.io/google-api-python-client/docs/epy/googleapiclient.http.HttpRequest-class.html) object. If the given API collection has a method named `list` that takes an argument called `cents`, you create a request object for that method like this:
>
> `request = collection.list(cents=5)`
>
> Creating a request does not actually call the API. To execute the request and get a response, call the `execute()` function:
>
> `response = request.execute()`
>
> Alternatively, you can combine previous steps on a single line:
>
> `response = service.stamps().list(cents=5).execute()`

Thus, for your code, you need to add `.execute()` to your delete line. E.g:

```
kwargs = {calendarId: 'primary',
          eventId: '9c9ppp94isp15103t54mtjss8s',
          sendNotifications: False}
rq = service.events().delete(**kwargs)
resp = rq.execute()
```

Comment: Of course it's the dumbest things. I somehow never noticed I was missing the execute.  Thanks.